# ParseObject.pinall(List<...>) not working on SyncService

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform

I'm using Android Sync Service to sync my ParseObjects from the cloud with the localDatastore but when I call `ParseObject.pinAll(...);` no exception is thrown but later on the app, if I query against the localDS I see no "pinned" objects.

My onPerformSync code:

```
//primeiro achar os novos/alterados no cel
        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryMobile = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Debit");
        queryMobile.fromLocalDatastore();
        queryMobile.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("updated_at", syncDate);
        queryMobile.whereNotEqualTo("debitStatus", DebitStatus.CLOSED.ordinal());

        //depois os online e comparar
        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryServer = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Debit");
        queryServer.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("updated_at", syncDate);
        queryServer.whereNotEqualTo("debitStatus", DebitStatus.CLOSED.ordinal());

        //pega os amigos e notificações online
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryServerFriends = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Friend");
        queryServerFriends.whereEqualTo("user_to", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        //queryServer.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("updated_at", syncDate);
        //queryServerFriends.whereEqualTo("has_answered",true);

        try {
            List<ParseObject> temp = null;
            temp = queryServer.find();
            ParseObject.pinAll(temp);
            Log.d("sync","Debits synced: "+temp.size());
            increaseSyncSuccess(syncResult, temp.size());
            temp = queryServerFriends.find();
            ParseObject.pinAll(temp);
            Log.d("sync","Friends synced: "+temp.size());
            increaseSyncSuccess(syncResult,temp.size());

        }catch (ParseException e) {
            if(syncResult != null && syncResult.stats !=null)
                syncResult.stats.numIoExceptions++;
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("sync",e.getMessage());
        }
```

And the debug messages:

> 11-30 21:56:06.481  26315-26346/com.maddogs.mymoney:sync D/sync﹕
>   Debits synced: 0 11-30 21:56:06.870 
>   26315-26346/com.maddogs.mymoney:sync D/sync﹕ Friends synced: 2

If i query the local I get no results:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> users = ParseUser.getQuery();
        users.fromLocalDatastore();
        users.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        users.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
                friends.addAll(parseUsers);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

parseUsers returns 0 result.

Is there any trick here or am I missing something ?

Thanks !

**--- Edit ---**

My Friend class has a pointer to the user class, so there is where I need to get the user from, according to the where query. My question is, do I need to call user.fetchIfNeeded() here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are querying ParseUser, but what you have pinned are Debit and Friend

if these objects contain a pointer to user, you need to include it in the query

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is, my Friend class has a pointer to the User class, so I'm not sure if I need to call User.fetchIfNeeded(). Gonna edit my question to clarify !

Comment: so in your Friend query, add query.include("${userFieldName}")

Comment: Thank you so much, adding `queryServerFriends.include("user_from");` did it !